# Error message on pathview()?

Tags: r

I am trying to use pathview() to overlay my gene expression onto KEGGS.. Something like this:

[kegg] [1]

I have used this code:

pv.out <- pathview(gene.data = merge2, gene.idtype="ENSEMBL",pathway.id = "04110", species = "dre", out.suffix = "ensembl_Cell_cycle", kegg.native = T, same.layer=T)

And this is my dataframe structure:

head(merge2) List1_logFC_transformed ENSDARG00000100344 -0.4250000 ENSDARG00000096038 -0.4250000 ENSDARG00000103955 -0.4250000 ENSDARG00000090824 -0.4250000 ENSDARG00000087743 -0.4250000 ENSDARG00000087699 -0.4250000 ENSDARG00000090734 -0.4250000 ENSDARG00000101977 -0.4250000
However, I am getting this error:

Error in UseMethod("select_") : no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "c('OrgDb', 'AnnotationDb', 'envRefClass', '.environment', 'refClass', 'environment', 'refObject', 'AssayData')" Note: None of the genes or compounds mapped to the pathway! Argument gene.idtype or cpd.idtype may be wrong.

Does anyone know why this might be? I had this working this morning... I am not clear why on a new machine this will no longer work! I cannot even get the example data set from the pathview() documentation, when this was working earlier!!

Thanks in advance

[1] : https://s10.postimg.org/9t02bo4w9/dre04672_ensembl_Intestinal_immune_network_for_I.png

Comment: Sounds like the `select` function was masked by some packages.  Try to restart R session and load `pathview` package last.

Comment: If that doesn't work, you should run deeper into the source code of `pathview` function.

Comment: Thank you very much, you were right, the dplyr() package masked the select function. I just needed to reorder when I load the package.